# problem in show persian string in some oracle tables

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I use win 10 and Pl sql developer 13. In some tables persian fields not show correctly and in the other show them correctly.
in other system that incorrect field showed in correct format and this is just my system's problem.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check collate and character set of your tables and columns, make sure their collates are **utf8_unicode_ci**

You can change collate by this query

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
    col1 VARCHAR(5)
      CHARACTER SET utf8
      COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```